# Laptop keyboard not working properly, Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: keyboard, ubuntu-18.04

Keyboard on my laptop randomly starts to act weird while running Ubuntu 18.04. This includes:

- Esc key stops working
- Right Alt key becomes the primary

Strange thing is that while this happens, the external keyboard continues working fine. Also, I don't face this problem while running Windows.

Answer (score 7):

Your laptop is certified by Ubuntu, so it should work fine.

You have to determine if the issue is with Linux itself or x11.

I'd try updating the x11 input drivers first.

```
sudo apt-get install -y xserver-xorg-input-all
```

if that does not check if linux itself is the issue.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/584011/a-key-on-my-keyboard-is-not-working

Answer (score 7):

This happened after I installed nouveau driver. Following are the steps that I had to do fix the mouse and keyboard problem.

- You need to login to grub.
- Upon boot press 'esc' you will go into the grub menu.
- Choose 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' -> 'Network'
- The root partition is mounted read-only. 
  To mount it read/write, enter the command

  `mount -o remount,rw /`
- Then choose 'root'
- In the root prompt install `sudo apt-get install -y xserver-xorg-input-all`
  In case you get unable to resolve hostname, you need to check the wireless connection. Follow the procedure as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62166/siocsifflags-operation-not-possible-due-to-rf-kill)
- Then, reboot the system

This should resolve the problems

Comment: Thanks a lot! This seems to have solved the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This has solved the problem for me too.

Comment: Thanks a lot !. I even can't using keyboard in normal boot - keyboard has been disabled. Then I must boot in recovery mode and do all your steps. All working as expected .

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with Ubuntu 18.04. I stumbled on the answer while trying the solution here.
Steps are here

1. Go to **settings** > **Universal Access** >  **Typing** Section
2. Click on **Typing Assist (AccessX)**
3. Turn off **Bounce Keys** Option

It Worked for me! I hope it will save someone's time.

This advice does not cover the case where an external keyboard is not seen at all.  Now 'the edit' is at least 6 characters long.  What a silly rule.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem! I kept stroking the keys like an idiot for about a month and surfed through the web across different solutions but none of them worked. Then I realized that I had accidentally enabled `sticky keys` from the accessibility menu. Disabling it worked fine for me.

> You should use `askubuntu.com` for problems related to Ubuntu. You will get better support.